# Facebook Graph API tagging places

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dictionary

I've created a story and been trying to add a popup with "some example data" to show up on the map as it shown below. Also inherited my new object inherited from `place` and in an action checked `Tag`, `Place` options.

So the result is

[image]

Then I want to add popup bound to pin on the map. I didn't find any information at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/

Is there any graph api properties kind of `og:popup:title`, `og:popup:content` using them Facebook will automatically add a popup widget into a map for story object?

[image]